# triyng to create a table with spring boot gradle and postgresql

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, gradle, spring-data-jpa

i'm triying to create a table using spring boot version 3.1.2 , gradle and postgresql
**this is my application.properties file
**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ribatSellerieDB
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=imen
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=TRACE

server.port=8081
```

**this is my entity
**

```
package models.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.io.Serializable;


@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "_user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id ;

    private String firstName ;

    private String lastName ;

    private String email ;

    private String password ;

}
```

**this is my repository **

```
package repositories;

import models.entities.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Integer> {
}
```

**and this is gradle.build
**

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.2.5.Final'
```

the problem here is when i run my appeverything go perfect except that the sql statment not showing and the table not created but ther is no error or warning

Comment: replace `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`